# initializing class properties before use in Swift/iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having trouble grasping the proper way of instantiating variables that always need to be set before an object is fully functional but may need to be instantiated after the constructor. Based on Swift's other conventions and restrictions it seems like there is a design pattern I'm unaware of.

Here is my use case:

- I have a class that inherits from UIViewController and will programmatically create views based on user actions
- I need to attach these views to this class, but to do so I need to retrieve their content based on configuration data supplied by another controller
- I don't care if this configuration data is passed to the constructor (in which case it would always be required) or supplied by a secondary call to this object before it is used

My problem seems to be that both of the approaches in bullet 3 seem flawed.

In the first case, there is only one legitimate constructor this class can be called with, yet I'm forced to override other constructors and initialize member variables with fake values even if the other constructors are never intended to be used (I'm also trying to keep these variables as `let` types based on Swift's best practices).

In the second case, I'm effectively splitting my constructor into two parts and introduce an additional point of failure in case the second part fails to be called prior to class being used. I also can't move this second part to a method that's guaranteed to be called prior to usage (such as viewDidLoad) because I still need to pass in additional arguments from the config. While I can make sure to call the `initPartTwo` manually, I'd prefer to have a mechanism that better groups it with the actual constructor. I can't be the first one to run into this and it seems like there is a pattern I'm not seeing to make this cleaner.

**UPDATE**:
I ended up going with a modified version of the pattern matt suggested:

```
struct Thing {
    let item1: String
    let item2: String
    struct Config {
        let item3: String
        let item4: String
    }

    var config:Config! {
        willSet {
            if self.config != nil {
                fatalError("tried to initialize config twice")
            }
        }
    }

    init() {
        self.item1 = ...
        self.item2 = ...
        ...
    }

    public func phaseTwoInit(item3: String, item4: String) {
        self.item3 = item3
        self.item4 = item4
        ...
    }
}

var t = Thing()
...
t.phaseTwoInit(...)
...
// start using t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an initial instance variable property value can't be supplied at object initialization time, the usual thing is to declare it as an Optional. That way it doesn't need to be initialized by the class's initializers (it has a value - it is `nil` automatically), plus your code subsequently can distinguished uninitialized (`nil`) from initialized (not `nil`).

If the Optional if an implicitly unwrapped Optional, this arrangement need have no particular effect on your code (i.e. it won't have to be peppered with unwrappings).

If your objection is that you are forced to open the door to multiple settings of this instance variable because now it must be declared with `var`, then close the door with a setter observer:

```
struct Thing {
    var name:String! {
        willSet {
            if self.name != nil {
                fatalError("tried to set name twice")
            }
        }
    }
}
var t = Thing()
t.name = "Matt" // no problem
t.name = "Rumplestiltskin" // crash
```

Comment: See the second part of this section of my book http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_why_optionals where I talk about how to "defer initialization of a variable".

Comment: But then all references to that variable have to use the question mark. Effectively two variables instantiated the same way (but at different time) will be accessed very differently. Is that really the optimal solution?

Comment: Not if these are implicitly unwrapped optionals. You can still check for `nil` if you are in doubt, but you can refer to them with no question mark and no exclamation mark.

Comment: Please try actually reading the part of my book I referred you to. I discuss all of this, with examples.

Comment: I read it, I like the implicitly unwrapped optional solution you describe but I'm still a bit confused since it seems to contradict Swift's other mantra/convention of always using a `let` to declare variables that will not change. With an implicit optional I have to use a `var` even though I only set the variable once (albeit not in constructor). This seems odd since Swift even goes out of the way to make such exception for regular member variables declared with `let` allowing them to stay `nil` until `init` finishes, so I'm surprised implicitly unwrapped optionals aren't compatible with `let`

Comment: You're correct but I don't see why you're surprised. Once object initialization is over, the door has _closed_ for setting a `let` instance variable; that is exactly what `let` _means_. Your entire proposal is that you want to set this variable _after_ object initialization, so clearly it _must_ be a `var`. What exactly is the issue you have with that?

Comment: The issue is that choosing constructor as the _door_  seems arbitrary, especially since there are multiple objects in user's code (and even in Apple's own code) that will not have finished completely initializing until after the constructor (i.e. in `viewWillLoad()` method). The point of `let` is to make sure the variable isn't redefined to a different memory position/value, not that it's set before some arbitrary moment in time (as long as it's set before being referenced). To me, the idea of allowing `let` to only be assigned to once, but when user wishes, seems much less arbitrary.

Comment: "The point of let is to make sure the variable isn't redefined to a different memory position/value, not that it's set before some arbitrary moment in time (as long as it's set before being referenced)." But the point of _object initialization_ is to ensure that all properties have values by the end of object initialization time. Swift's rules do ensure that. If you don't like that, switch to Objective-C, which doesn't care (and opens the door for incoherent object initialization).

Comment: By the way, if your real underlying issue is that you'd like a way to ensure that an Optional instance variable, despite being `var`, is changed only once in its lifetime, from `nil` to non-nil, that is an easy contract for _you_ to arrange with a setter observer.

Comment: Thanks,  multiple settings is indeed what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: @melheor If you have a lot of these, you might wrap all your late-initialized values in a struct with `let` properties and a memberwise initializer. Now you can guard the struct against being set more than once, and once it _is_ set, its properties are fixed. You could also privatize the setter and force the caller to pass through a public method that can add as a further guard. Or use computed properties as a facade. There isn't much you can't arrange if you are serious about it!

Comment: To make sure I understand you correctly, you're suggesting defining `willSet` observer on the variable pointing to the struct itself and moving all the variables inside the struct with `let` keyword for each, then creating that an instance of that struct from my delayed initialization logic?I like this, since having `let` keyword preceding these variables also allows me some visual sanity when reading the code, [like Joel recommends](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html).

Comment: Correct, and I'm also saying, if other classes need access to these variables after they are initialized, make this struct private and force those other classes to pass thru accessor methods (aka computed read-only instance variables).